# How to get the up vector of my object in libgdx/box2d?

Tags: java, libgdx, box2d

I'm rotating my object(ship) to face a target with the code below.

`playerBody.setTransform(playerBody.getPosition(),        MathUtils.lerpAngle(playerBody.getAngle(), getDesiredAngle(),lerpProgress));`

I want to to move the ship in the direction the ship is looking. I thought that retrieving the Up vector of the ship would suffice. I tried the below code but that didn't work.

```
            Vector2 direction = playerBody.getWorldPoint(new Vector2(0,1));
        playerBody.setLinearVelocity(direction.nor());
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe that getWorldPoint() does not give you what you are looking for. It returns the vector (direction + distance) of a local point, in regard to the **box2D world's origin**. In this picture, this would be the blue vector: [getWorldPoint()](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3aLfn.png). What you want is the red vector.

The most basic way of doing would be something like this :

```
float angle = playerBody.getAngle();
Vector2 direction = new Vector2(MathUtils.cos(angle),MathUtils.sin(angle))
```

I must add that in my case, I had to add 90°, since I needed an angle of 0° to correspond to a vertical body :  `angle = playerBody.getAngle() + MathUtils.PI/2f`